# One Node App per Package.json

Tags: web-services, node.js, package, project

I am new to Nodejs but come from a predominantly .net background. In there it is normal to have multiple asp.net projects within one solution. Such as a web service, a web front end and then a load of framework and shared logic.

Now coming to nodejs I was planning on doing a similar thing, having one *solution* with 2 project, one being a web service style app and one being a front end app, both of which would be using the same frameworks and would have some shared logic in the project to.

The current folder structure looks like:

```
|- root
   |- source
      |- framework
      |- web-service
      |- web-ui
   |- tests
   |- build-scripts
|- package.json
```

Now in the above example framework will contain lots of shared stuff, such as models, repositories, factories etc. Then the web service will just deal with saving and exposing data, then the front end just has a view with calls to the web service. So is the above use case ok? as currently I just build with jake and output 2 folders with app.js files and then just run then separately, but just wanted to know if this is bad practice or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the node convention is just to make each of `framework`, `web-service`, and `web-ui` independent npm modules with their own `package.json` files, then for the combined project have a separate 4th module that lists each of the other modules as a dependency. npm supports a wide variety of URL schemas including git (or github) repository URLs using tagged releases.

So I suggest:

```
projects/
  framework/
    package.json
  web-service
    package.json //depends on framework
  web-ui/
    package.json //depends on framework
  uberproject/
     package.json //depends on web-service, web-ui, and maybe framework as well
     //Use URLs like git+ssh://git.example.com/projects/framework.git#v0.9.4
```

Also read up on `npm link` (or just use symlinks) when you want to concurrently work on both `uberproject` and `framework`, for example.

Comment: I read about the link command, but I work in a windows environment, and apparently that does not work in windows due to the lack of symbolic links. However I will look more into the structure you mention above, as that would make sense as each project would describe its own dependencies. The only thing that is a bit of a problem in this scenario for me is that my actual files are written in typescript, and are pretty much useless without running through the build script to process and package them. So in this instance all projects are built at the same time, but I guess this can change.

Comment: Yeah you might end up having to use a workflow like `cd web-ui`, build it, then `cd uberproject` and `npm install ../web-ui`. It's not a clean as npm link but it may work. Another thing to consider would be organizing uberproject with git submodules for the dependencies instead of real npm modules.